# how to remove duplicate times in ruby

Tags: ruby

how can i make it to read the same time just one time only. this is my codes

```
    state = station_info_state[/[^_]+/]

    query = " select * from #{state} where MAIN_ID = #{main_id} order by date_taken ASC, TIME ASC " #order by date_taken ASC, TIME ASC "

    state = DB["#{query}"]

    @last_daily_rainfall = 0
    CSV.open("./rainfall_tideda/#{@station_info_station_id}_rf.csv", "w+") do |csv|
        csv << ["#{@station_info_station_id}", "INCREMENTAL", "#{@station_info_station_name}"]
        state.each do |line|

            time_taken = line[:'time'].to_i

            time_taken = format('%04d', time_taken).to_s

            simulated_time_taken = time_taken.to_s.gsub(/.{2}(?=.)/, '\0:')

            date_taken = line[:'date_taken'].to_s

            date_taken = Date.parse("#{date_taken}").to_s

            date_taken = date_taken.gsub( "-", "/" )

            current_daily_rainfall = line[:'daily_rainfall']
            if(current_daily_rainfall >= 0 && current_daily_rainfall != '-9999')
                this_daily_rainfall = current_daily_rainfall - @last_daily_rainfall

                if(this_daily_rainfall > 0)
                    csv << [ "#{date_taken}", "#{simulated_time_taken}", "#{this_daily_rainfall}" ]
                else
                    if(this_daily_rainfall != '-9999' && this_daily_rainfall == 0)
                        csv << [ "#{date_taken}", "#{simulated_time_taken}", "0" ]
                    end
                    if(this_daily_rainfall != '-9999' && this_daily_rainfall <  0)
                        csv << [ "#{date_taken}", "#{simulated_time_taken}", "#{current_daily_rainfall}" ]
                    end
                end
                @last_daily_rainfall = line[:'daily_rainfall']
            end     
        end
    end
```

[duplicate time image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVb8c.jpg)
the result are shown in the image description. In the result, you can see got many duplicate time

Comment: Welcome to SO, take a moment and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a hash which stores the dates/times you've already seen:

```
processed_date_times = Set.new
```

Then, in your iteration, add entries:

```
processed_date_times.add([date_taken, simulated_time_taken])
```

And then only add the entry if it hasn't been processed yet:

```
unless processed_date_times.member?([date_taken, simulated_time_taken])
  # ... add row to csv
end
```